# how to get day wise data in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

[db screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sm5A.png)
how to get  day wise data in  MySQL database
expected Output

```
    ID   |   Name  |   DAY
   --------------------------
    1    |    A    |   SAT
    2    |    B    |   SAT
    3    |    C    |   SUN
    4    |    D    |   MON
    5    |    E    |   TUES
    6    |    F    |   WED
```

Comment: but whats receive_date's current data format ?

Comment: Never store date format as text in your case `varchar(60)` and provide sample data. As @AliFidanli suggested without knowing the  receive_date's current data format we can not provide a solution. We only can guess.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `receive_date` as datetime format

```
   select id as ID, 
          name as Name, 
          upper(date_format(receive_date, '%a')) as DAY 
   from table_name ;
```

If you just have `receive_day`

```
select id as ID, name as Name, upper(receive_day) from table_name.
```

The question is very unclear. Hope this info might help.